# Moviepy Rendered Video File Doesn't Have any Sound

Tags: moviepy

I have just taken a simple video clip and made a rendered video of it using `moviepy`. This is my code :

```py
import moviepy.editor as mpe 

video_clip = mpe.VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
audio_clip = mpe.AudioFileClip("closer.mp3")

video_clip.to_videofile("testingaudio.mp4",audio_codec = 'aac',audio = True)
```

The video is created. I even played it in `VLC` but there is no audio in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the audio clip to the video clip before writing it to a file.

Example:

```py
import moviepy.editor as mpe 

video_clip = mpe.VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
audio_clip = mpe.AudioFileClip("closer.mp3")

video_clip = video_clip.set_audio(audio_clip)

video_clip.write_videofile("testingaudio.mp4", audio_codec='aac')
```